# How to submit a form and get some text in return using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrr1awvj/2/) code:

```js
$("form.signupform").submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var data = $(this).serialize();
var url = $(this).attr("action");
var form = $(this); // Add this line
$.post(url, data, function(data) {

$(form).children(".signupresult").html(data.signupresult);
$(form).children(".signupresult").css("opacity", "1");

});
return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="signupform" method="post" action="admin/signupinsert.php">

<p class="signupresult"></p>
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
</form>
```

Signupinsert.php page code:

```
// Code to insert data into Database
$signupresult = "Some value here";

$response = new \stdClass();
$response->signupresult = $signupresult;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode($response);
```

Expected Result:

When user clicks on submit form button, the code runs in background. And submits the form without reloading the page.

And the `signupinsert.php` page return some text, and its text display on a paragraph with class `signupresult`.

And the form can be submitted unlimited times, without reloading the page.

**Problem:**

The form only gets submitted once. If I try to submit it twice, "Nothing Happens" (No values inserted into database, no value returned in paragraph with class `signupresult`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: It looks like you might be missing an `e.preventDefault()` inside your jQuery submit watcher...

Comment: Side note you should do `var form = $(this);` first so you can use that variable instead of repeating the $(this) jQuery constructor.  And in your post success remove the $() from around form.  It's already a jquery object.

Comment: Ah.  You have it commingled with an inline `onsubmit`.  I'd recommend removing that, and simply adding the `e.preventDefault()` into your jQuery submit function.

Comment: Fix the few tweaks we've recommended, and then it doesn't appear there's any reason your form should only submit once.  Use your browsers developer tools, particularly the "network" tab, to watch "XHR" activity.  What happens? Does it post again? If so, what is the response?

Comment: @Taplar - agreed! I was editing the comment as you submitted that, because I agree, that wierdness could be causing the problem.

Comment: Updated my code https://jsfiddle.net/Lrr1awvj/3/  removed `onsubmit` line..and added `e.preventDefault();`..Check the code please. But it is sitll not working, same result..

Comment: Guys, the problem is something else..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell your request that you expect JSON as return.  Else data.signupresult doesn't make sense; data is seen as a string.

I always use $.ajax, never $.post; I find it easier to add options.

```
$.ajax({
  url: $(this).attr("action"),
  dataType: 'JSON',
  type: 'post', 
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    ...
  }
})
```